# Way to get specific keys from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a way to get specific keys from a dictionary.

In the example below, I am trying to `get all keys except 'inside'`

```
>>> d
{'shape': 'unchanged', 'fill': 'unchanged', 'angle': 'unchanged', 'inside': 'a->e', 'size': 'unchanged'}
>>> d_keys = list(set(d.keys()) - set(["inside"]) )
>>> d_keys
['shape', 'fill', 'angle', 'size']
>>> for key in d_keys:
...     print "key: %s, value: %s" % (key, d[key])
...
key: shape, value: unchanged
key: fill, value: unchanged
key: angle, value: unchanged
key: size, value: unchanged
```

Is there a better way to do this than above?

Comment: why do you do `set(d.keys())`? keys should already be unique

Comment: because you can't use set operations otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python 3.X most of dictionary attributes like `keys`, return a view object which is a set-like object, so you don't need to convert it to set again:

```
>>> d_keys = d.keys() - {"inside",}
>>> d_keys
{'fill', 'size', 'angle', 'shape'}
```

Or if you are in python2.x you can use `dict.viewkeys()`:

```
d_keys = d.viewkeys() - {"inside",}
```

But if you want to only remove one item you can use `pop()` attribute in order to remove the corresponding item from dictionary and then calling the `keys()`.

```
>>> d.pop('inside')
'a->e'
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['fill', 'size', 'angle', 'shape'])
```

In python 2 since `keys()` returns a list object you can use `remove()` attribute for removing an item directly from the keys.

Answer (score 1):

a cross-version approach:

```
d = {'shape': 'unchanged', 'fill': 'unchanged',
    'angle': 'unchanged', 'inside': 'a->e', 'size': 'unchanged'}

d_keys = [k for k in d.keys() if k  != 'inside']

print(d_keys)
```

**Output:**

```
['fill', 'shape', 'angle', 'size']
```

---

expanding it a bit:

```
def get_pruned_dict(d, excluded_keys):
    return {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k not in excluded_keys}

exclude = ('shape', 'inside')
pruned_d = get_pruned_dict(d, exclude)

print(pruned_d)
```

**Output**

```
{'fill': 'unchanged', 'size': 'unchanged', 'angle': 'unchanged'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use remove() built-in.

```
d = {'shape': 'unchanged', 'fill': 'unchanged', 'angle': 'unchanged', 'inside': 'a->e', 'size': 'unchanged'}

d_keys = list(d.keys())
d_keys.remove('inside')

for i in d_keys:
    print("Key: {}, Value: {}".format(d_keys, d[d_keys]))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a good way to do this if you need to keep the original dictionary the same.

If you don't, you could `pop` the key you don't want before getting the keys.

```
d = {'shape': 'unchanged', 'fill': 'unchanged', 'angle': 'unchanged', 'inside': 'a->e', 'size': 'unchanged'}
d.pop('inside')
for key in d.keys():
     print "key: %s, value: %s" % (key, d[key])
```

This will mutate `d`, so again, don't use this if you need all of `d` somewhere else. You could make a copy of `d`, but at that point you're better off just iterating over a filtered copy of `d.keys()`. For example:

```
d = {'shape': 'unchanged', 'fill': 'unchanged', 'angle': 'unchanged', 'inside': 'a->e', 'size': 'unchanged'}
ignored_keys = ['inside']
for key in filter(lambda x: x not in ignored_keys, d.keys()):
     print "key: %s, value: %s" % (key, d[key])
```

Comment: you should use the `{}` and format string methods instead of `%s` it's more pythonic. Not to mention if you use `d.keys()` its wasteful here because you can easily get a tuple of key:value with `d.items()` Also if you pop you should supply an arg of `None` to prevent some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in d_keys:
    if key not in ['inside']:
        print "key: %s, value: %s" % (key, d[key])
```

Comment: Or, create a list like `ignore=['inside', ]`, and then `if key not in ignore ...` which is a more general solution when dealing with more than one special key.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need with inside but this will give your result.

```
for key in d.keys:
    if key != 'inside':
         print "key: %s, value: %s" % (key, d[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little benchmark comparing a couple of good posted solutions:

```
import timeit

d = {'shape': 'unchanged', 'fill': 'unchanged',
     'angle': 'unchanged', 'inside': 'a->e', 'size': 'unchanged'}


def f1(d):
    return d.viewkeys() - {"inside", }


def f2(d):
    return filter(lambda x: x not in ['inside'], d.viewkeys())

N = 10000000
print timeit.timeit('f1(d)', setup='from __main__ import f1, d', number=N)
print timeit.timeit('f2(d)', setup='from __main__ import f2, d', number=N)

# 5.25808963984
# 8.54371443087
# [Finished in 13.9s]
```

Conclusion: f1 not only is better in terms of readability but also in terms of performance. In python 3.x you'd use keys() instead.

So I'd say @Kasramvd answer is the right one for this post

Comment: When I run this code in Python 3 (changing `viewkeys` to `keys`), `f2` is faster than `f1` by a similar amount. When I run it unchanged in Python 2. I also see `f1` as faster, confirming your results in Python 2.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with a dict comprehension for example to only get evens.

```
d = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d'}
new_d = {k : v for k,v in d.items() if k % 2 == 0}
```

for your case because of complaints.

```
d = {'shape': 'unchanged', 'fill': 'unchanged', 'angle': 'unchanged',         'inside': 'a->e'}
new_d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k != 'fill'}
#you can replace the k != with whatever key or keys you want
```

Comment: I think this was supposed to be on a different question.

Comment: why? if the point was to filter a dictionary based on a criterion then this answers it.

Comment: Because OP's dictionary isn't a set of numbered keys. I know the technique is generalizable, but answers should solve the specific problem in the question.

Comment: Just modified it to answer specifically @MorganThrapp also if you were doing pop he will have overhead because `pop` could potentially lead to an empty dict and throw an error of popping empty dict.